# SQL | Clean data by CONTINUOUS matching process

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's try to explain it in the cleanest ways.

What is the best way, to clean databased by continuous matching?

Let's say I have two tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B. ANd I would like to match variable values, like money. I take table A and matching with B where A_X=B_X and so on.

**HERE IS THE TRICKY BIT** which I'm not sure how to do it in a clean way. I need a way for the continuous cleaning process, so that when I matching table A with B (AND TABLE **B** DO NOT INCLUDE MATCHED VALUES FROM the FIRST ATTEMPT) and then match table A with B (when **B** do not contain matched data from the 1st and 2nd attempt)

I'm looking for CLEANEST WAY as currently, I use common table expression and basically telling when values do not exist in 1st, then 1st and 2nd, and so on... which makes SQL query EXTREMELY complicated and limited.

**DATA FLOW**

- http://prntscr.com/ldlgu0

**SQL SAMPLE CODE:**

```
--#####################################################################
WITH INT1 AS (

SELECT 
CMS.Store_name AS STORE_NAME,
CMS.Date AS A_DATE,
CMB.ENTRY_DATE AS B_DATE,
CMS.Cash AS A_CASH,
CMB.AMOUNT AS B_CASH
FROM `TABLE_A_DATA` AS CMS
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B_DATA` AS CMB
ON CMS.store_name = CMB.STRAIGHT_LOOKUP
AND ROUND(CMS.Cash/50,0)*50 = ROUND(CMB.AMOUNT/50,0)*50
AND CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%F",CMB.ENTRY_DATE) AS STRING) = CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%F",DATE_ADD(CMS.Date, INTERVAL 1 day)) AS STRING)
),
--#####################################################################
INT2 AS (

WITH DATES AS (SELECT DISTINCT STORE_NAME,A_DATE  FROM INT1 WHERE B_DATE IS NULL),
TABLE_B_CLEANED_DATA AS (SELECT 
CMB.* 
FROM `TABLE_B_DATA` AS CMB 
LEFT JOIN INT1 AS INT1
ON INT1.STORE_NAME = CMB.STRAIGHT_LOOKUP
AND INT1.B_DATE = CMB.ENTRY_DATE
AND INT1.B_CASH = CMB.AMOUNT
WHERE INT1.B_DATE IS NULL
)

SELECT 
CMS.Store_name AS STORE_NAME,
CMS.Date AS A_DATE,
CMB.ENTRY_DATE AS B_DATE,

CMS.Cash AS A_CASH,
CMB.AMOUNT AS B_CASH
FROM `TABLE_A_DATA` AS CMS
INNER JOIN DATES 
ON CMS.Date = DATES.A_DATE
AND CMS.Store_Name = DATES.STORE_NAME
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B_CLEANED_DATA AS CMB
ON CMS.store_name = CMB.STRAIGHT_LOOKUP
AND ROUND(CMS.Cash/50,0)*50 = ROUND(CMB.AMOUNT/50,0)*50
AND CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%F",CMB.ENTRY_DATE) AS STRING) = CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%F",DATE_ADD(CMS.Date, INTERVAL 2 day)) AS STRING)
),
--#####################################################################
INT1C AS (SELECT * FROM INT1 WHERE B_DATE IS NOT NULL),
INT2C AS (SELECT * FROM INT2)
--#####################################################################
SELECT * FROM INT1C UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INT2C
--#####################################################################
```

As per Google Big Query documentation - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements
the limit is 200 updates per day, so to use a status update and so on, not the best way.

**PS.** As it was mentioned in the comments, I'm using WAVE way, each WAVE data is cleaning.

Comment: Please add some data and the expected result. A few rows will go a loong way for us to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm more looking for the theoretical solution, I will put if this question will be too hard, but basically, I need this small section, the way to use the same table and clean it by each step.

Comment: @TheImpaler have add SQL code

Comment: @TheImpaler have added the data flow diagram

Comment: After reading your questions a few times, I think you are processing the data in multiple "waves" in order to clean it gradually. Now, if you are doing that I would strongly suggest to have some kind of "status" or "matching group" column that tells you which rows are already matched (or even tell you on which group/month) they were matched. This way you don't need to re-process rows that are already matched, just for the sake of the latest month. I think you are right to think that your query as it is is processing too much... (on every query execution?).

Comment: @TheImpaler That is really good idea, I will have a try at let you know

Comment: @TheImpaler One question regrding your feedback, is it possible to do they way you said with out acrually have a physical table? (like view, or temprorary table)

Comment: @TheImpaler As per documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements BigQuery has a limit with the update, so I need another method, for example, to use VIEWs and so on.... ((((